# alter temporarily type of column in tabular

Tags: tables

Suppose I have a tabular environment with some type of columns.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{6}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{..}
  hello & hello2 \\
  \hline
  1.32 & 2.55 \\
  5.788 & 134.449 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like the line containing `hello & hello2` to be formatted differently, for example as normal left-aligned text, the same that you would obtain with

```
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
```

How can I selectively for a single line (or single element) in the tabular change the type of the tabular element?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{l}{some left cell}`

Answer (score 2):

Beside solution suggested in @Ulrike comment, you may try to use `tabularray` and `siunitx` (loaded as `tabularray` library) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, si={table-format=1.3}] 
                      Q[l, si={table-format=3.3}]}
            }
{{{hello1}}}    & {{{hello2}}}  \\
  \hline
  1.32          &   2.55        \\
  5.788         & 134.449       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]